# Allow Google Drive SDK on Android to connect to an app-owned account

Tags: android, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm looking for the possibility of making an android app that connects to a Drive account to upload files. The restriction is that this account should be a service account and not the user's account.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts Shows how to do it on the server-side of an application, but is it possible to do this in Android?

I understand that the SDK was not design for this purpose, but are there any workarounds to do this? Is it even possible?

Any sort of example or guidance is welcome. I want to use the Drive SDK for its resumable upload protocol, so I would also welcome other alternatives to do resumable uploads on Android.

Comment: It looks like you should be able to do that using the Java API. However, you'd need to distribute the credentials (private key, etc) with your app, which is a security hole the size of the Grand Canyon, especially if you intend to store sensitive, user-specific data on there.

Comment: That is a big concern, would getting all the credential's info/keys from a server be a better alternative? Also, if I use the JAVA API to get the credentials can I still access the methods to create files in the Drive API?

Comment: Transferring private keys is equally insecure. It's vulnerable to replay attacks, and you still don't have secure storage if the device is rooted. I haven't tried it, and I wouldn't for this purpose, but the Java API should be fully usable in Android -- a better solution would be to have a web-service wrapper to pass authentication tokens, or pass through data.

Comment: I will consider this to make sure its secure. I've used the Java API to log in with the user's credential before, however I couldn't find a way to interact with the drive API. Then it's just a matter of knowing how to get the credentials form the Java API and use them to interact with the Drive API, of course if this is even possible

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do with Google Drive Android API now:

- Open File
- Create a File
- Compress File
- Use File Content
- Use Folders
- Queryin for Files
- MetaData

Comment: Thanks, Creating a file is what I need. But can it be done using an app-owned account instead of a user account?